# Add custom field in Layered Navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

How to add size range in layered navigation? just like price range.

Comment: what did you try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's default functionality.

Please define the size attribute to be "Price"  type,  then set it as "Used in Layered Navigation". Reindex and you are done.

Comment: Thanks! I find this useful :) cant vote up this answer yet coz it requires me 15 reputation..

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach adds the currency symbol for many.