# Range in custom attribute in magento, layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, filter

I want to show custom attribute in range in layered navigation like the price is shown in range

```
  £20.00 - £30.00
  £30.00 - £40.00
  £40.00 - £50.00
```

i want custom attribute `Length` in Range

```
 1.00 - 2.00 Meter
 2.00 - 3.00 Meter 
 3.00 - 4.00 Meter 
 4.00 - 5.00 Meter
```

I saw a few related questions (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/34036/24017) which says use **Price** Catalog Input Type, i have tried it but it gives currency symbol in it and i want length unit (meter, cm, etc.).

Comment: I still did not found any solution, guys any help will be appreciated..